# Prevent creating a tree that can have a loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to create a tree. The idea is simple. Each Node have one single parent Node. I want to be able to assign a parent Node to any Node that will not cause the tree to malform ( have a loop )

What I am trying to do is as follow

```
public class Node
{
    public string ParentNodeId {get;set;}
    public string BreadCrumb {get;set;}
    public bool IsLeaf {get;set;}

    public void AssignToParent(Node ParentNode)
}
```

With the idea is that I will maintain a BreadCrumb string that reflect the whole parent chain that for example,

```
nodeD 
{
ParentNodeId: "C"
BreadCrumb: "A,B,C"
IsLeaf: true
}

nodeE
{
ParentNodeId: "B"
BreadCrumb: "A,B"
IsLeaf: true
}
```

I have an understanding that is: At parent asignment time, a loop can appear only if the current node (being added as a child) is inside the BreadCrumb of any leaf of this parent node.

Let's say that we are assigning nodeC as the parent of nodeA. We can detect that the leaf D have a breadcrumb that contains A,B,C which signify that we should not assign C as the parent of A.

*Edit: To clarify I am trying not to have to have to traverse the whole tree, starting from the parent to find loop, especially when/if I am using ORMs that may cause many db visits unless I am writing custom SQL scripts.*

*Edit2: The most frequent operations I will do on this tree are:

- Assign/unassign a node as the parent of the current node.
- List all child nodes under a node

The tree is just a simple hierarchy like departments in multiple companies that belong to a conglomerate. Sometimes you just want to pick a single department and move it to another company but never want a developer under a department to "own" the whole conglomerate. Or maybe think the Windows folder/registry structure?

My question: Is this a good strategy to block causing loops without having to always traverse the tree? Did I have a wrong understanding? Am I over-complexify thing?

Comment: Depending on your needs and if I am understanding this correctly, just check the node you are adding is not a references of the parents, a simple loop would iterate up the tree.

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral I am worrying a bit about the performance and how to put that structure into DB. Pulling records one by one for the loop from DB could be quite slow. Therefore I think of loading the tree up, flattened by selecting StartsWith("A") and work with everything as flat list is fast. 
But upon further thinking, detaching a node from the tree seem cause me trouble as I will need to rewrite all BreadCrumb of all child

Comment: SqlServer has HierarchyId which has methods/tools especially for this type of issue, however they are poorly support in EF (if you are using it), so the bread crumb idea might be your best shot.

Comment: You should not have to store the bread crumb. That is redundant information that should follow from the ancestors of a node.

Comment: You might get better feedback if you could convey what kind of metaphor the tree represents and how it might be used once constructed.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Updated so that you can understand it more clear

Comment: Be conscious that having no loops is not a strong enough condition for a graph to be a tree: what you'll obtain is a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).

Comment: Compute the bread crumb. Storing it will lead to trouble.

Comment: @m.raynal This would be true if the tree was defined by storing a list of links to the children in each parent. But the OP is doing the opposite: storing a link to the parent in the child.

Comment: When you move a node to a different parent, you need to update the breadcrumbs of all the items that are decendents of the moved node? I don't think storing the breadcrumb is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are data structures meant to track disjoint sets. The purpose of the data structure is to be able to perform the following two operations:

- check if two elements are in the same set
- combine two sets

In particular one I use is disjoint set forest with [union by rank and path compression optimizations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find-algorithm-set-2-union-by-rank/). Although it sounds really complex in fact it is easy to implement.

Now if you have this structure the problem you are solving is trivial - you will add a cycle if you make a node `X` the parent of node `Y` if and only if `X` and `Y` belong to the same set. Otherwise you should combine the sets of `X` and `Y`.

Note that the solution I propose is both more efficient in terms of memory usage and faster.